# how to install ubuntu 22.04 desktop on raid array?

Tags: 22.04

I've searched the forum a bit and can't find the answer. I use exactly the desktop version of ubuntu, I dived into the Linux system not so long ago. but I have a need to install the system specifically on raid array 0. Installing a Linux server with a desktop installation does not suit me, the system slows down too much and does not work as I would like. if someone knows how or if he can tell me how to install ubuntu desktop directly on the array, I will be very grateful. p.s. I tried mdadm, but either I'm missing something, or vice versa, I don't know something, collecting an array and installing the system at the end of the installation, a message pops up that grub cannot be installed in this section .....

Comment: Installing directly in the array can be done but it's not recommended. It's always preferable to use a fast drive (SSD) independent of the array for the OS. Then, within the OS, it's much easier to manage any kind of storage.

Comment: The fact is that my server does not require any kind of close attention for the safety of information. i need high read and write speed and large hdd or ssd capacity. all my programs are written to the root of my home directory and I do not have the ability to separate the recording into different media. therefore, it is more convenient for me to create an array by increasing the volume and speed and install the system in it

Comment: Looking around the internet there's not a lot to find of people actually installing 22.04 LTS to a RAID 0, but this one found to install 21.10 and then upgrade it to 22.04.  https://palm2000.com/otherProjects/installingUbuntuDesktop2110OnRaid0.php  One issue is that 21.10 is EOL and no longer supported, but you could still upgrade it by using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  You are more than welcome to [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1430449/edit) your question and give us exact steps and errors that you have received in your attempts to install.